# How to handle Firebase Auth account-exists-with-different-credential Errors

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Both [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/microsoft-oauth#handling-account-exists-with-different-credential-errors) and [Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/microsoft-oauth#handling-account-exists-with-different-credential-errors) detail how to handle the error `account-exists-with-different-credential` which occurs when trying to sign in to an account that is already set in firebase auth with a given email. However the [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/microsoft-oauth)  documentation has no such details and in fact the explicit [error documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) doesn't provide any additional info.  The piece that seems to be missing is that with iOS and Web, when the error occurs, the credentials are still returned, but I can't seem to find them with the exception on Android. So how do you use the [link with credentials](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking) methods if you never received the credentials (even though the sign in was successful)?

Comment: This could help:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/209
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException.html

Comment: @fractalix Thanks for the info, but these actually just highlight the problem. Yes, the error can be returned, but it isn't returned with the credentials, which are needed. For example Here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/microsoft-oauth#handling-account-exists-with-different-credential-errors the Error is returned, but you can grab the credentials with `var pendingCred = error.credential;` and use that to link accounts. The credentials are returned on Web and iOS, but not Android.

Comment: FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException has the method getUpdatedCredential to do exactly that:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException.html#public-authcredential-getupdatedcredential-

Comment: Pleade check below link for your query :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40012816/firebase-auth-with-email-and-password-check-user-already-registered/40013189#40013189

Comment: @fractalix According to this documentation it is only thrown when using PhoneAuthCrendetial https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException and in fact, in my case it is null when called. This seems like the bug to me

Comment: @AshokKumar Those answers aren't valid. The first answer asks you to fetch other providers before hand with the email, except during OIDC/SAML login, I don't collect the email, the provider handles the login.  The other answer isn't valid either as I don't actually want more than one email address to exist in the system. This issue is not Firebase auth specific, as iOS and Web have solutions. It's a bug/gap in the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You may follow these steps:-

i. Go to console from your firebase https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/

ii. Select your application

iii. Then go to the Authentication option > sign-in method

iv. In the advanced section you can see **One account per email address**

v. Then change it to **Allow creation of multiple accounts with the same email address**