# How to detect the google sign in account which one have stored to database?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am creating user application which supported email and google sign in authentication and firebase database. Everytime, I signed first time with Google Account, the account data is stored the firebase database as new user record. However, I find the problem when I signed out and sign in with the previous same Google account. How can I know the Google Account has registered and stored to Firebase eventhough signOut?. My Logic is when the user sign in with Google Account on first time, the account data will be stored to firebase database, the application will detect the account has registered and stored to database or not.

There are the code of LoginActivity.java class and ProfilActivity.java class that related with my problem.

LoginActivity.java class

````
package co.id.roni.usertestapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class LoginUserActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1001;
    private static final String TAG = "Google Activity";
    TextView tvDaftarLinkPage;
    Button SignIn;
    FirebaseAuth signInAuth;
    FirebaseUser signInAuthUser;
    EditText emailSignIn, passSignIn;
    SignInButton googleSignInButton;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    boolean isGoogleSignIn;

    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_user);
        SignIn = findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
        tvDaftarLinkPage = findViewById(R.id.tv_register_link_text);
        emailSignIn = findViewById(R.id.edt_email_signin);
        passSignIn = findViewById(R.id.edt_pass_signin);

        googleSignInButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in_google);
        googleSignInButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        signInAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        signInAuthUser = signInAuth.getCurrentUser();
        tvDaftarLinkPage.setOnClickListener(this);
        SignIn.setOnClickListener(this);

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.tv_register_link_text:
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginUserActivity.this, RegisterUserActivity.class));
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.btn_sign_in:
                signInProcess();
                break;
            case R.id.btn_sign_in_google:
                signInWithGoogle();
                break;
        }

    }

//    sign In with Google
    private void signInWithGoogle() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
//                updateUI(null);
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
        }
    }

    //process google account sign in
    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(final GoogleSignInAccount account) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + account.getId());
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
        signInAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");

                            //variabel isGoogleSignIn is used for checking sign in google

                            isGoogleSignIn = true;
                            FirebaseUser user = signInAuth.getCurrentUser();

                            //the problem code is here! How I can detect the google user account has stored and registered 
                            if (user != null) {
                                String uid = user.getUid();
                                reference.child(uid).child("uid").setValue(uid);
                                reference.child(uid).child("name").setValue(user.getDisplayName());
                                reference.child(uid).child("email").setValue(user.getEmail());
                                reference.child(uid).child("photo").setValue(String.valueOf(user.getPhotoUrl()));


                            }
                            startActivity(new Intent(LoginUserActivity.this, ProfilUserActivity.class));
                            finish();

                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        }

                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
//                        hideProgressDialog();
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
    }

//this method for login with email. this is success
    private void signInProcess() {
        final String email = emailSignIn.getText().toString();
        final String pass = passSignIn.getText().toString();

        if (email.isEmpty()) {
            emailSignIn.setError("Tidak boleh kosong");
        } else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            emailSignIn.setError("Email tidak valid");
        } else if (pass.isEmpty()) {
            passSignIn.setError("Password tidak boleh kosong");
        } else if (pass.length() <= 6) {
            passSignIn.setError("Password minimal 6 karakter");
        } else {
            signInAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).addOnCompleteListener(LoginUserActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginUserActivity.this, ProfilUserActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        Log.e("Pesan", "Gagal Sign In : " + task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```
````

ProfilActivity.java class

```
package co.id.roni.usertestapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class ProfilUserActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener {
    TextView namaProfile, emailProfile;
    ImageView photoImageProfile;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuthMain;
    FirebaseUser user;
    DatabaseReference profileDb;
    GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient;
    boolean isGoogleSignIn;
    private static final String TAG ="Pesan" ;
    GoogleSignInOptions gso;


    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profil_user);
        Button btnEditProfile = findViewById(R.id.btn_edit_profile);
        Button btnSignOut = findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_out);
        namaProfile = findViewById(R.id.tv_nama_profil);
        emailProfile = findViewById(R.id.tv_email_profil_page);
        photoImageProfile = findViewById(R.id.img_profile_page);

        firebaseAuthMain = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = firebaseAuthMain.getCurrentUser();

        if(user != null){
            showProfile();

        }

        btnEditProfile.setOnClickListener(this);
        gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,gso)
                .build();
        btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void showProfile() {
        profileDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user.getUid());
        profileDb.getRef().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                emailProfile.setText(dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString());
                namaProfile.setText(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString());
                Picasso.get().load(dataSnapshot.child("photo").getValue().toString()).centerCrop().fit().into(photoImageProfile);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.e("Pesan", "Gagal Load"+databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view.getId() == R.id.btn_edit_profile){
            startActivity(new Intent(ProfilUserActivity.this, EditProfileActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
        if(view.getId() == R.id.btn_sign_out){
            if(user != null){
                firebaseAuthMain.signOut();
                //every sign out, user can choose another gmail but the problem is how to know the gmail has registered
                Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(ProfilUserActivity.this, UserMainActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                });

//                goog.signOut().addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
//                    @Override
//                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
//
//                    }
//                });
            }
            else{
                Log.e("Status", "Gagal Keluar");
            }


        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(TAG, "message"+connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
    }
}
```

I expect the application can detect which the gmail account has registered and stored to firebase database so that the Profile Page just showed data from the database

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40012816/firebase-auth-with-email-and-password-check-user-already-registered . This might help you.

Comment: I would like to say sorry It's not solution I want, Sir. the case is just ensuring google sign in has stored database after sign in first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with below code. As it checks if user is not null and will execute the code and until it reaches start activity function, all your Google data will be stored in Firebase. If data is not sent then it might not start the activity.

```
if (user != null) {
     String uid = user.getUid();
     reference.child(uid).child("uid").setValue(uid);
     reference.child(uid).child("name").setValue(user.getDisplayName());
     reference.child(uid).child("email").setValue(user.getEmail());
     reference.child(uid).child("photo").setValue(String.valueOf(user.getPhotoUrl()));
     startActivity(new Intent(LoginUserActivity.this, ProfilUserActivity.class));
     finish();
 }
```