# How to check if email was already used in firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Cloud Firestore. I wrote the following code in my sign-up activity:

```
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(users_email, users_password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            try {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "createUserWithEmail:success");
                    addNewUser(users_email);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Log.w(this.getClass().getName(), "createUserWithEmail:failure",
                            task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.failed_to_register,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

It works great. If user entered an email that already being used then it won't work. But if user entered an email and the same password that was used for the email it will login. This is not the behavior I want. How can I check if the email was already used and fail in that case?

Comment: Are you using firebase authentication using email and password ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yes I'm

Comment: Then it doesn't matter.  I have an app too. When I try to use same email for sign up. It toasts an error that email is already in use.. in my login activity . or you need to be more clear what your problem is

Comment: In my case, it toast that email is already is in use, only if the password that was used in the sign-up is different. If I already signed up with `test@gmail.com` ans pass `1234` and then I'll try to sign up with the same email, it will fail (which is ok), but if I will try to sign up with same email and same password then it will login (instead of showing error).

Comment: You'll need to call `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` and see if there are any providers for that email already. The usual flow is that you first ask the user to enter their email address, then call that API, and then move them to a screen that either asks for the rest of their registration details (if they're new), or shows them the provider(s) with which they're signed up already. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40012816/firebase-auth-with-email-and-password-check-user-already-registered/40013189#40013189